# free software to create employee database

Tags: database

I want a software which stores my employees name,address and salary details .Also I should be able to search the record by name,address etc . Is there any free software that does this simple task? 
EDIT:Is there a software that creates such portable programs where there are custom fields name,address,sex etc and I can put my company's name on interface.

Comment: What OS must it run on? And by "free", do you mean like in "free beer" (no cost) or "free speech" (open-source)?

Comment: Why does a spreadsheet like LibreOffice not work for you?

Comment: it should run on windows.I dont care if its open source or not but it should be freeware

Comment: Then what is wrong with @BasilBourque's suggestion? It's the first thing that came to my mind. Welcome aboard, but please read [ask], so that you can help us to help you

Comment: simply because it does not look professional

Answer (score 1):

Try  sentrifugo.  http://www.sentrifugo.com/ It's a opensource and have many advance features  (It's a web version,so Set it up on Local Company servers and use it with in the company)
Also you can use this site to find the alternatives http://alternativeto.net/software/sentrifugo/?license=opensource

Comment: These seems a bit more complicated

Comment: More complicated than what? You didn't exactly give detailed requirements.